# How do you implement volume control using Cast Companion LIbrary?

Tags: android, chromecast, google-cast

I am trying to implement volume control using the Cast Companion Library. I am a bit confused how it should be done though.

Originally, I had been using VideoCastManager.onDispatchVolumeKeyEvent, which worked fine, until I turned on the lockscreen feature, which apparently prevents this method from actually doing anything:

https://github.com/googlecast/CastCompanionLibrary-android/blob/master/src/com/google/sample/castcompanionlibrary/cast/VideoCastManager.java#L2074

It is not really clear in any of the instructions how one is to implement volume control, other than using the method I tried. I would basically like to default to controlling the cast device via the hardware buttons in all cases possible, while casting. Any suggestions?

Comment: Have you tried the CastVideos-android sample that uses CCL and provides volume control? Give that a try and if it works for you, see what you are doing differently in your project.

Comment: I will try it. It is also important to me to understand what the "lockscreen" feature means exactly, and why it would prevent the volume callback from doing anything. Might be nice to add a comment there for future people if it is not obvious.

Comment: Ok so in the android cast videos example, you control the volume in 2 different ways, by calling incrementVolume directly (not sure why), by calling onDispatchVolumeEvent (which uses incrementVolume with a guard against if we are connected and using the lockscreen). Yours still works in the latter case though, where-as mine doesn't. Unfortunately, I cannot just copy your implementation for a variety of reasons. Can you perhaps let me know how the volume gets changed when you are playing a stream, and in the playback screen, and onDispatchVolumeEvent is a no-op? Thank you!

Comment: I am not sure where you see the code that I call incrementVolume() directly and again through onDispatchVolumeKeyEvent(). Regardless, if you turn on the lockscreen feature, you will get RemoteControlClient which in turn allows you to change volume without you calling incrementVolume().

Comment: Re: Calling incrementVolume directly, I think my local copy is very old. It used to be here : https://github.com/googlecast/CastVideos-android/blob/90403152b7c6f105228c796c0d08b77d3550c4ec/src/com/google/sample/cast/refplayer/mediaplayer/LocalPlayerActivity.java#L578

Comment: ok so it seems my problem is then related to RemoteControlClient. I am actually using RemoteControlClient in my own code, and there may be a conflict there. I will see if it works as expected if I remove my own calls, that exist for when I am not casting. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Turns out my problem was that I using

setVolumeControlStream(AudioManager.STREAM_MUSIC);

in my base activity which was overriding what the CCL was doing for me. Remember to remove any calls to this when you implement this.

Thanks to ali-naddaf for being very helpful.